# ModelMapper issues converting DTO Objects to Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, dto, modelmapper

I have a simple spring-boot app where `Product` needs to be stored and conversion between DTO and Entity needs to happen. I am using the `ModelMapper` dependency. User can attach a `ProductCategory` to the `Product` or leave it empty. Similarly `Product` can have multiple `ReplaceNumber` or empty. If I dont attach category it gives error. If I attach category it saves the product with the attached category. If I leave the `replaceNumbers` array empty it saves. If I fill it it gives errors. Errors are described below.

**ProductCategory**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product_categories")
public class ProductCategory
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String name;

    public ProductCategory()
    {

    }

    public ProductCategory(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**ReplaceNumber**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "replace_numbers")
public class ReplaceNumber
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String partNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    public ReplaceNumber()
    {

    }

    public ReplaceNumber(String partNumber)
    {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }
}
```

**Product**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products", indexes = {@Index(name= "part_number_index", columnList = "part_number", unique = true)})
public class Product
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "part_number", nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String partNumber;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "product",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<ReplaceNumber> replaceNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProductCategory category;
}
```

Following are the DTO Classes that need to be converted.

**ReplaceNumberRequest**

```
public class ReplaceNumberRequest
{
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String partNumber;

    public String getPartNumber()
    {
        return partNumber;
    }

    public void setPartNumber(String partNumber)
    {
        this.partNumber = partNumber;
    }
}
```

**ProductCategoryResponse**

```
public class ProductCategoryResponse
{
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public ProductCategoryResponse()
    {

    }

    public ProductCategoryResponse(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**ProductRequest**

```
public class ProductRequest
{
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 20)
    private String partNumber;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String description;

    private List<ReplaceNumberRequest> replaceNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    private ProductCategoryResponse category;
}
```

**ProductService**

```
@Service
public class ProductService
{
    @Autowired
    ProductRepository productRepository;

    public Product create(ProductRequest productRequest)
    {
        Product product = new Product();

        org.modelmapper.ModelMapper modelMapper = new org.modelmapper.ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.map(productRequest, product);

        return productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```

If I post the following `JSON` from `Postman`

```
{
  "partNumber": "443455783",
  "description": "443434",
  "replaceNumbers": [],
  "category": ""
}
```

It goes for saving the empty category and produces the following error.

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : org.walana.GP.model.Product.category -> org.walana.GP.model.ProductCategory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : org.walana.GP.model.Product.category -> org.walana.GP.model.ProductCategory
```

If I post the following `JSON` from `Postman`

```
{
  "partNumber": "443455783",
  "description": "443434",
  "replaceNumbers": [
    {
        "partNumber": "123455"
    },
    {
        "partNumber": "343435"
    }
    ],
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Mounting"
  }
}
```

It gives following error.

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [part_number_index]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Comment: `"category": "" ` means sending empty string instead of category object

Comment: It means empty category object

Comment: `"category": ""` doesn't mean empty category object.

Comment: so how to achieve the saving?